# save Ø in mysql table and not Ã˜

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters, character

My table look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` 
(
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
    `fb_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '0',
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',

) TYPE=MyISAM charset=utf8;
```

I add to the db like this:

```
            $sql = "insert ignore into `friends` (`id`, `fb_id`, `name`)" .
                            "values (:id, :fb_id, :name)";
                try 
                {
                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $fb_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $result = $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->closeCursor(); 
                }       
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                die ($e->getMessage() ); 
                }
```

How can I save`Øystein` and not `Ã˜ystein`. I have set the charset to `utf8` not sure what more I can do.

EDIT:

Upgraded my db_connect function:

```
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
        $driver_options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8' );

        try
        {
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $driver_options);
        }
```

Still got the same problem..

Comment: Did you solve the problem or run my test code?

Comment: Please share your final solution with us, since it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$this->db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')` after connecting to the DB.

Comment: Do you mean `$result = $stmt->execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`, it did not work..

Comment: @ganjan try `SET NAMES utf8` as well

Comment: Nope, after connecting to the db:

$this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $driver_options);

$this->db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell the browser which text encoding to use on the page, which submits the form and the page, which later on shows the result retrieved from the database?

In the header of your HTML page should appear this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: I am using this : `<meta charset=utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try running `SET NAMES utf8`: [How to make PDO run SET NAMES utf8 each time I connect, In ZendFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584676/how-to-make-pdo-run-set-names-utf8-each-time-i-connect-in-zendframework)

Comment: I updated my `db_connect` function as you can see, but that did not help. I think i am using `SET NAMES` correctly..

Comment: Hmm, I doubt it will make a difference, but could you try making the 'UTF8' lowercase?

Comment: Moreover, you might want to try explicitly sending the charset header... take a look here: https://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/03/23/make-your-website-completely-utf-8-friendly/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the charset to the DSN like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ';charset=UTF-8';
```

Could you run this test code to track down the problem a step further?

```
<?php

echo '<html>'
   . '<head>'
   . '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'  
   . '</head>'
   . '<body>'
   ;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASS', 'root' );

$dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME . ';charset=UTF-8';

$db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 

$id = 12;
$fb_id = '23';

if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'name'] )) {

    echo '<form method="POST" >Strange letters go here <input type="text" name="name"></form>'
       . '</body>' 
       ;
    exit;
}

$name = $_POST[ 'name'];


$sql = "insert ignore into `friends` (`id`, `fb_id`, `name`)" .
                            "values (:id, :fb_id, :name)";
try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $fb_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    echo 'OK';
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die ($e->getMessage() );
}

$sql = 'SELECT *'
     . 'FROM `friends` '
     ;

try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    while( $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

        echo '<br />' . print_r( $result );

    }

    $stmt->closeCursor();

    echo 'OK';
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die ($e->getMessage() );
}


echo '<body>';
```

If I submit this

```
öäüÖÄÜß
```

the page reads and emits back this

```
öäüÖÄÜß
```

while I see this in phpMyAdmin (likely an bug in phpMyAdmin):

Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼Ã–Ã„ÃœÃŸ