# How can I convert json data?

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got json data. There is "cyrillic" strings in json file, like this one:

```
\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043D\u043E\u0432 \u0418.
```

When I decode json and put this data in database table I get the string

```
Ð˜Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð² Ð˜.
```

On [one decoding web-site](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) I entered this string and got very good (the one I need)

```
Иванов И.
```

And also this site told me that it was converted from CP1252 to UTF-8. 
So I tried to convert data from json after decoding manually using

```
mb_convert_encoding ( $string, "UTF-8","windows-1252");
mb_convert_encoding ( $string, "UTF-8","CP1252");
```

and

```
iconv("windows-1252","UTF-8",$string);
iconv("CP1252","UTF-8",$string);
```

Any of this functions made the string in database table look like

```
ÃËœÃÂ²ÃÂ°ÃÂ½ÃÂ¾ÃÂ² ÃËœ.
```

or

```
ÃÂ˜ÃÂ²ÃÂ°ÃÂ½ÃÂ¾ÃÂ² ÃÂ˜.
```

both are not decoded on above site properly. So the question is, how do I convert this string?

**Upd:** used this sql request:

```
ALTER DATABASE logenterprise
    CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Tried after the same things that wrote above - result is the same.
Also tried this just in case:

```
alter table mytable convert to CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: It might have to do with the charset that your table was setup for. verify that the table itself has a charset assigned to it that can represent those characters.

Comment: my database is in utf8_general_ci

Comment: Collation is not the same as the table and column charset.

Comment: If you are looking it via http server set <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> tag too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curse you damned encodings ^^
They gave me a hard time too.

Everything looked fine (database, encoding of the inputdata and on the website), but still i got cryptic chars in my tables. So what's the problem then? It's the connection to your database-server.

Fortunately you can fix this with a simple query.

Right **after** establishing the mysql-connection you need to execute the following query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Voilà. When you execute your INSERT-Query the data gets nicely saved in your db.

This saved my ass many times as i was handling 'Umlauts' and the €-sign.

---

**Note:** You shouldn't use mysql_xxx methods anymore as they are deprecated. I just used them in the example to make the code clearer.

Comment: thanks, added a string to my application.ini:
`resources.db.params.charset = utf8` (answer provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584676/how-to-make-pdo-run-set-names-utf8-each-time-i-connect-in-zendframework))