# Zend PDO insert cut string before an umlaut

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, utf-8

I want to use the Zend Framework 1.12 PDO insert function to save some datas. I get the following array:

```
array (size=2)
  'ticket_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  't_title' => string 'Foo Ä Bar' (length=9)
```

I call the insert function and save the id with title. After i check the databas and only the id and title Foo submitted. The string got cut if there is an umlaut wihout an exception and i dont know why..
When I enter manually through phpmyadmin umlauts it works.

The column t_title is set as 'utf8_unicode_ci' and 'varchar(255)'.

The database connection:

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "host"
resources.db.params.dbname = "db"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "pw"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8;"
```

Did you ever seen this problem?

Comment: When I look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584676/how-to-make-pdo-run-set-names-utf8-each-time-i-connect-in-zendframework it doesn't have the semi-colon behind the `SET NAMES utf8`. Perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. I don't think it helps if I say that your source PHP files should be in UTF-8? You must have realized that. (at least for anything you put in the database)

Comment: I removed the charset and driver_options. Now it works fine..

Comment: Whatever next! :-)